# Problem after the installation magento2

Tags: magento2, adminhtml

After the installation, adminhtml doesn't work, how to fix it? Thanks

[image]

Comment: Please attached screenshot or error, this info is not enought.

Comment: Saphal Jha, screenshot is attached

Comment: have you configured it on https?

Comment: Saphal Jha, were i can configure it?

Comment: are you working on local or server?

Comment: working on local server

Comment: so now you need to change the in core_config_data table , change web/secure/use_in_adminhtml,web/secure/use_in_frontend to 0 then flush the cache then check it.

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change values to 0 of below path in core_config_data table:

```
web/secure/use_in_adminhtml,
web/secure/use_in_frontend
```

then flush the cache then check it.